# Pressing 'Enter' in the HTML code cause some redundant margin in the result

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.block{
  background-color:#ecbbbb;
  Display:inline-block;
  width:50mm;
  height:20mm;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center
}
.gap{
  background-color:#bc6565; 
  Display:inline-block;
  width:4mm;
  height:20mm;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<p>This is true</p>
<div style="width:320mm;">
<div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div>
</div>

<p>This is weird (have enter in the HTML code)</p>
<div style="width:320mm;">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="gap"></div><div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Why pressing `Enter` in the HTML code cause some redundant margin in the result??
I am using Google Chrome version `61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 2):

Please use `float:left` to avoid extra spaces. Still you want to use `display:inline-block` then give `font-size:0` to its parent div.

```css
.block{
  background-color:#ecbbbb;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50mm;
  height:20mm;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center
}
.gap{
  background-color:#bc6565; 
  display:inline-block;
  width:4mm;
  height:20mm;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center
}
.block1{
  background-color:#ecbbbb;
  float:left;
  width:50mm;
  height:20mm;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center
}
.gap1{
  background-color:#bc6565; 
  float:left;
  width:4mm;
  height:20mm;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<p>If you want to use display inline-block then use font-size:0; to parent div</p>
<div style="width:320mm;font-size:0">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
</div>

<p>This is done by float:left</p>
<div style="width:320mm;overflow:auto">
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="gap1"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="gap1"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="gap1"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="gap1"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="gap1"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
</div>
```